# Error while using Scrapy : ['scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole': No module named conch twisted]

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

In Ubuntu 13.04, I have installed Scrapy for python-2.7, from the tarball. Executing a crawl command results in the below error:

> ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole': No module named conch

I've also tried installing twisted conch using easy_install and using the tarball. I have also removed the scrappy.egg and .info and the main scrappy folder from the python path.

Reinstalling scrapy does not help as well.

Can some one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu, you should avoid using `easy_install` wherever you can.  Instead, you should be using `apt-get`, `aptitude`, "Ubuntu Software Center", or another of the distribution-provided tools.

For example, this single command is all you need to install scrapy - along with every one of its dependencies that is not already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-scrapy
```

`easy_install` is not nearly as good at installing things as `apt-get`.  Chances are the reason you can't get it to work is that it didn't quite install things sensibly, particularly with respect to what was already installed on the system.  Sadly, it also leaves no record of what it did, so uninstallation is difficult or impossible.  You may now have a big mess on your system that prevents proper installations from working as well (or maybe not, you might be lucky).  It's difficult to say whether this is the case, since there are a lot of different pieces that go into a working system, and they all need to fit together just right, and it's difficult to enumerate them so you can check them, let alone enumerate the ways they can each be broken.

Comment: Don’t use the `python-scrapy` package provided by Ubuntu, they are typically too old and slow to catch up with latest Scrapy. From the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have the python development headers:

   `apt-get install build-essential python-dev`
2. Install scrapy with `pip`:

   `pip install Scrapy`

Comment: You quoted half of the documentation and then got lost.  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu

Comment: Your answer is clearly not recommended, it even states in the link of your comment. The steps shown in my answer are the recommended method. Maybe to avoid embarrassment you should delete your answer.

Comment: I'm not embarassed to make mistakes.  Making mistakes is a big part of how you learn.  I'm also not so concerned with how I *look* that I need to hide the fact that sometimes I don't know the answer.  In this case, my answer was perhaps incomplete.  If we read the page you linked to, there are instructions for setting up a native package repository which contains up-to-date scrapy packages.  Having done this, you can correctly install a new version of scrapy using the system package manager using `apt-get` - which is better than doing something naive with pip, though virtualenv + pip may be ok

Comment: `which is better than doing something naive with pip` - something naive...like using the standard python package manager. I don't have time for coder's with egos. Down voting the most correct answer, I am disgusted with you for striving for yourself, your ego and not for better code.

Comment: I'm sorry you're disgusted.  Maybe this will help, <http://bit.ly/1N44sW9>.  I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone It takes a lot of time and testing for binaries to be included in the trusted repos of `ubuntu` or `debian`. If you want to stay up to date use the language level package managers, compile yourself or in the worst case scenario add untrusted sources to `apt` as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu packages**
New in version 0.10.

Scrapinghub publishes apt-gettable packages which are generally fresher than those in Ubuntu, and more stable too since they’re continuously built from Github repo (master & stable branches) and so they contain the latest bug fixes.

**To use the packages:**

Import the GPG key used to sign Scrapy packages into APT keyring:

**Step.1**

*sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 627220E7*

Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list file using the following command:

**Step.2**

*echo 'deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list*

Update package lists and install the scrapy-0.24 package:

**Step.3**

*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24*

**Note**

Repeat step 3 if you are trying to upgrade Scrapy.
Warning

python-scrapy is a different package provided by official debian repositories, it’s very outdated and it isn’t supported by Scrapy team.